# Load child items of node in treeview from remote source

Tags: android, treeview, load

I know how to achieve the below using Treeview model when i have all the data before i load the view
[image]

But my issue is the following: intialy i only have the first level

[image]

When user click expand on a level i have to call a webservice and retrieve the child then populate them as childs of this node to become like this

[image]

So my question is how to achieve this, what should i do after i called the web service and retrieved the childs of this? do i have to reload the whole tree?

Comment: I also need it .Any answer pls sugest me

Comment: I changed the way it works. now i load all the content before i create the treeview and then  create it. so the load issue when i expand is no more applicable